# Use OrderBy of AngularJS to loop the list for navigation ordered by Index ascending

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi how can i order the ng-repeat to order the Object-array to a specific ordering following their index keys into ascending order.

```
$scope.paneContainer = {books:[{}] } ;  
$scope.paneContainer.books[0].science = { title:"science", content:"web/app/views/partials/science.html"  };
$scope.paneContainer.books[0].alphabets = { title:"alphabets", content:"web/app/views/partials/alphabets.html"  };
$scope.paneContainer.books[0].folks = { title:"folks", content:"web/app/views/partials/folks .html" };
```

Then on front end:

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in paneContainer.books[0] track by $index | orderBy:$index " class="">
        <strong>{{tab.title}}</strong></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Desired output is:

Science

Alphabets

Folks

Currently angular orders the list by alphabetically.

Comment: Why does your data model look like that?? It's not working because objects don't have an order to their keys, and `$index` is an angular generated value. It has nothing to do with the key's placement in the object. Couldn't you just push all the book objects into the book array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Mike said, objects don't have an order.  If you didn't want to change it to an array for some reason (which is probably the easiest and best option), you could add a displayOrder property to the object and then use a filter to sort it by displayOrder.

```
angular.module('app').filter('orderByDisplayOrder', function () {
    return function (obj) {
        var array = [];
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
            array.push(obj[key]);
        });
        array.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.displayOrder - b.displayOrder;
        });
        return array;
    }
});
```

Then you could use that filter to do the sorting.

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
<li ng-repeat="tab in paneContainer.books[0] track by $index | orderByDisplayOrder" class="">
    <strong>{{tab.title}}</strong></a>
</li>
```

Comment: yes i mistakenly was thinking $index was used to order the object items. unforunately ng-repeat seems to be not working on array loops so i deliberately put objects-array to setup the items - or is it just me on 1.2.8 angular version that encounters this - or my mistake again. anyhow thanks for figuring this wrinkle for me comrad!